# using $pull query in mongodb to fetch data from array of objects but seems like its not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I need help to delete images from the database. so anyone please help here is the codes
here's the image deletion query from MongoDB

```
module.exports.editCampground = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  console.log(req.body);
  //const campgroundss = req.body.campground;
  const campground = await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    ...req.body.campground,
  });

  const img = req.files.map((f) => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
  campground.images.push(...img);
  await campground.save();
  //to delete selected image from array

  if (req.body.deleteImage) {
    for (let filename of req.body.deleteImage) {
      await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename);
    }
      await campground.update({ $pull : {images : {filename: {$in: req.body.deleteImage } } } })
    console.log(campground);
  }

  req.flash("success", "successfully updated existing campground");
  res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`);
};
```

with this code, I am able to delete images from Cloudinary but images are still shown on my carousel...

```
//ejs code

 <div class="mb-3">
                <% campground.images.forEach(( img , i)=> { %>
                <img src="<%= img.url %>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="....">
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteImage[]" id="image-<%= i %>" value="<%= img.filename %> ">
                </div>
                <label for="image-<%= i %>">delete?</label>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
```

campground schema where I defined schema for images

```
const campgroundSchema = new Schema({
         title:String,
         images:[{
            url : String,
            filename : String
         }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can remove values from and array and save it to DB

```
campground.images = campground.images.filter(image => !(image.filename === req.body.deleteImage));
  await campground.save();
```

This is how Array.filter() works:

```js
const images = [{ filename: 'a' }, { filename: 'b' }, { filename: 'c' }, { filename: 'd' }, { filename: 'e' },]

const imagesWithoutB = images.filter(image => !(image.filename === 'b'))

console.log(imagesWithoutB)
```

Comment: but it is deleting the entire array not a particular element...

Comment: `Array.filter()` returns the array with elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: There was a typo indeed, which I fixed, also included snippet example